# Show that an ideal $\langle n \rangle \subset \mathbb{Z}$ is primary if and only if $n$ is (up to sign) a power of a prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Show that an ideal $\langle n \rangle \subset \mathbb{Z}$ is primary if and only if $n$ is (up to sign) a power of a prime.

Definition: An ideal $I$ is primary if whenever $fg \in I$ then either $f \in I$ or $g^m \in I$ for some $m>0$.

For the forward direction: Suppose $I=\langle n \rangle$ is primary. Then if $fg \in I$ then either $f \in I$ or $g^m \in I$ for some $m>0$. How would I continue?

Comment: You've just written down the definition of 'primary'. What have you actually tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $n$ is not a power of a prime; then for some prime $p$ dividing $n$ you can write $n=p^km$, where $m>1$ and $\gcd(m,p)=1$. Now try to show that although
$p^km\in\langle n\rangle$, no powers of either $p^k$ or $m$ are contained in $\langle n\rangle$.

For the reverse direction, it shouldn't be difficult to show that the ideal $\langle p^k\rangle$ has the desired property. If $fg$ is divisible by $p^k$ and $f$ is not divisible by $p^k$, then what can you say about $g$?

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, the question is inaccurately posed: when $n=0$ you have a primary ideal too.

Hint (useful in both directions)

Let's suppose $I$ is a nonzero ideal of $\mathbb Z$. The radical of $I$ is an intersection of finitely many maximal ideals of $\mathbb Z$. If two different maximal ideals are involved, the radical cannot be prime.  Factorizations tell you what maximal ideals are involved.

The radical of a primary ideal is always prime, of course